# Swift - How to wait for something without making the app hanging

Tags: swift, macos, while-loop, wait

I have a code like this:

```
    print("Migration Execution: Successfully uninstalled MCAfee")
    migrationInfoPicture.image = NSImage(named: "Unroll")
    migrationInfoText.stringValue = NSLocalizedString("Unrolling from old server... Please wait!", comment: "Unrolling")
    while(!readFile(path:logfilePath)!.contains("result: 2 OK")) {
        searchLogForError(scriptPath: scriptOnePath)
    }
    print("Migration Execution: Successfully unrolled from old server")
    migrationInfoText.stringValue = NSLocalizedString("Setting up MDM profile... Please wait!", comment: "Setting up MDM")
    while(!readFile(path:logfilePath)!.contains("result: 3 OK")) {
        searchLogForError(scriptPath: scriptOnePath)
    }
```

It actually works in the background, reading from the file works and logging works but since the GUI will be hanging executing a while loop with a quickly completed task, the image and the text changes will not be visible.

Code for searchForLogError is:

```
func searchLogForError(scriptPath:String) {
    if((readFile(path:logfilePath)!.filter { $0.contains("ERROR") }).contains("ERROR")) {
        print("Migration abborted")
        migrationInfoPicture.image = NSImage(named: "FatalError")
        migrationInfoText.stringValue = NSLocalizedString("An error occured: \n", comment: "Error occurence") + readFile(path:logfilePath)!.filter { $0.contains("ERROR") }[0]
        migrationWarningText.stringValue = NSLocalizedString("In order to get further help, please contact: mac.workplace@swisscom.com", comment: "Error support information")
        self.view.window?.level = .normal
        btnExitApplicationOutlet.isHidden = false
        getScriptProcess(path:scriptPath).terminate()
        return
    }
}
```

How can I achieve a visible change of NSImage and NSLocalizedString while constantly looking for log file change without a hanging GUI (or even with a hanging GUI, but with enough time to change the visible elements between the while-loops)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Polling file system resources is a horrible practice. **Don't do that**. There are dedicated APIs to **observe** file system resources for example `DispatchSourceFileSystemObject`

Create a property

```
var fileSystemObject : DispatchSourceFileSystemObject?
```

and two methods to start and stop the observer. In the closure of `setEventHandler` insert the code to read the file

```
func startObserver(at url: URL)
{
    if fileSystemObject != nil { return }

    let fileDescriptor : CInt = open(url.path, O_EVTONLY);
    if fileDescriptor < 0  {
        print("Could not open file descriptor"))
        return
    }
    fileSystemObject = DispatchSource.makeFileSystemObjectSource(fileDescriptor: fileDescriptor, eventMask: [.write, .rename], queue: .global())

    if fileSystemObject == nil {
        close(fileDescriptor)
        print"Could not create Dispatch Source"))
        return
    }
    fileSystemObject!.setEventHandler {
        if self.fileSystemObject!.mask.contains(.write) {
           // the file has been modified, do something

        }
    }
    fileSystemObject!.setCancelHandler {
        close(fileDescriptor)
    }
    fileSystemObject!.resume()
}

func stopObserver()
{
   fileSystemObject?.cancel()
   fileSystemObject = nil
}
```

Comment: It works thank you very much. Now, it really takes long, when I try to change text and picture from this mask.contains, I have a delay of several seconds. Is there a possibility to speed that up?

Comment: That's another question. It depends on the kind of the log file. Maybe it's sufficient to read only the last few (kilo)bytes from the file

Comment: Thank you very much, I managed to get it to a stable status. :)